# DDD One aggregate, two possible data sources

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a scenario where we’ve decided to pull some functionality in-house which we should have done a long time ago because it’s part of our core domain. As part of the transition we will temporarily be working with either an external service to store and retrieve `Widget`s or our database depending on the type. When interacting with our local database we’ll be using optimistic concurrency which will add a `version` field to our `Widget` that is not present when interacting with the external service.

What is the canonical domain driven design solution here? What is the best way to abstract this and where should it be implemented? My first instinct was to implement an abstract factory pattern in the application service layer, but one could argue that this could all be abstracted into the repository. In such a way when we pull out the external service consumers won’t need to make a change. Since we are using aggregate design and don’t have an overly complex use case we don’t need to worry about a unit of work or anything like that. Transactional concerns are maintained entirely within the repository.

Comment: How do you ensure atomicity between both data stores right now? You can't really have an AR stored in 2 separate DBs.

Comment: To be clear the entire aggregate is stored in one place, but that could be one of two data stores depending on the type. This hasn’t been built yet - just looking at ways to ease the transition while adding incremental value.

Comment: What locking mechanism is available for the external store if optimistic locking is not supported?

Comment: This is a full scale third party `Widget` service - we don’t have control over how concurrency is handled. We have workarounds for this, but I think that’s out of scope or not really the intent of this question. Great questions though!

Comment: Are you actually writing to that API or you are just reading? If you are writing to me it seems like they need to provide some kind of locking mechanism and your application must know about it or else a lost update could occur.

Comment: Writing, but we have a partitioned queuing mechanism to handle this

Comment: It's not about concurrency. It's about overwriting an older version. E.g. Client 1 loads screen, client 2 loads screen and save changes. Client 1 save changes. Client 2 changes are overwritten and no one notices.

Comment: Let’s not get into these details too much. Assume we don’t have concurrent users just yet and ignore concurrent user sessions. This is really getting off topic although again all great questions.

Comment: I would abstract this in the repository and perhaps use the composite pattern to treat both repositories as one from the application's perspective. The only thing is that a single interface may be difficult if you pass an expectedVersion which is not supported by external repo impl.

Comment: Not sure what you had in mind with the composite pattern here? As for the expected version I was planning to rely on the relevant repository to handle that. The version would be a field on the domain model, but would be unchanged by domain logic. When sent to the repository for persistence it would automatically increment by 1. There would be a unique constraint on the entity ID + version number.

Comment: Posted an answer. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the repository is responsible for the storage abstraction I think it would be the repository's responsibility to coordinate with multiple storages as well.

You could implement something similar to:

[image]

Now if you must support an `expectedVersion` you could make it clear in the interface's contract that `expectedVersion` may not be supported by all implementations and will throw or simply won't be honored.

> "There would be a unique constraint on the entity ID + version
> number."

That works for concurrency conflicts, but won't prevent non-concurrent lost updates anyway e.g.

1. Client C1 loads widget W(v1) on screen.
2. Client C2 loads widget W(v1) on screen.
3. Client C2 make changes and saves (e.g. update description).
4. Repository loads W(v1) in memory and saves back W(v2).
5. Client C1 make changes and saves (e.g. update description).
6. Repository loads W(v2) in memory and saves back W(v3).

In the end the `description` update by C2 was lost silently. You'd generally solve this problem by sending the expected version along with the command.

Comment: Yes good point about the concurrency "lost" updates. Sometimes depending on your tolerance for this sort of thing in your particular domain you can get away with not caring about the expected version so long as the command/mutation is valid given the _current_ state of the model (where current is whatever you retrieved when the request came into your service). You probably also want to make sure the version is sequential, but again concurrency was intended to be out of scope of the question.

Comment: I think you've made a fairly convincing argument - The one thing that makes me wonder if there is, perhaps, a better solution here has to do with the fact that we're now making calls to external services in a repository. If we have good aggregate design we typically shouldn't have calls spanning multiple repositories, but if we do and we have to implement something like a unit of work we could potentially be making a call to an external service and thereby blocking an open transaction.

Comment: Well, it's not the AR boundaries that are wrong, it's the AR storage that is distributed. As long as each AR is either internal or external it makes sense, but one AR should not be split across distinct storages. There is no distinction between a DB on another tier and your external service. Both can be seen as external services.

Comment: Yeah that’s fair point - I made this same exact point to my coworker. I was tempted to treat these entirely separately, but would just be wayyy too much throw away work.